# Where can I make (2D and) 3D cartesian coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm in need of a program that makes 3D cartesian coordinate system. I have to make a presentation and I have to make my own referentials. I've tried programs like Paint 3D and desmos and I couldn't do it, because I can never make one right. I needed one that would give me the model, where I can add coordinates or not, label with what I want, where I can rotate them as I want or change places and have several in the same image.

I had images of what I meant but I don't have yet 10 reputation to do it, but I think I made myself clear anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest [Calcplot3D](https://c3d.libretexts.org/CalcPlot3D/index.html) and [Math3D](https://www.math3d.org/), both of which allow you to add coordinates, label with what you want, where you can rotate it, etc.

[image]

Comment: I used Math3D and I did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend GeoGebra 6 (https://www.geogebra.org/)